# testNG org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\..\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Please help me on this critical issue

I have been getting this error this morning, My script was working perfect last night. When i turn on my computer and see my firefox gets updated to 47.0 and when i started my script, i get this error message, last time when i get similar issue updated  selenium server with latest version and my script goes fine. But this time i found that selenium server latest version is still 2.53.0 that i updated last time - not sure what should i update.

I have been using Selenium server 2.53.0 Current Firefox version is 47

Note: I downgraded my firefox to 46.0.1 but still geting the same issue.

Can i go with Firefoxdriver.exe  if yes than please share link.

Here is my TestNG Trace in more detail:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
,"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true}
1465408689376   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1465408689376   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1465408689376   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1465408689378   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1465408689380   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1465408689380   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1465408689380   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1465408689381   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0
1465408689381   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1465408689382   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.2.6
1465408689397   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1465408689403   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1465408689650   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1465408689650   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1465408689650   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1465408689652   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1465408689823   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1465408689824   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1465408689827   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1465408689849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1465408689849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1465408689849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1465408689852   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1465408689853   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1465408689878   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1465408689887   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1465408698285   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1465408698286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0
1465408698286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.2.6
1465408698446   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1465408698447   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1465408698447   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1465408698447   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1465408698447   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1465408698448   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1465408698449   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1465408698449   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1465408698449   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1465408698451   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1465408698453   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

Build info: version: '2.49.1', revision: '7203e46', time: '2016-01-21 17:35:35'
System info: host: 'AGERA-LT26', ip: '10.100.20.218', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at watts.ParentModule.BaseInit.startUp(BaseInit.java:98)
    at watts.CustomerManagement.test.testjobs(test.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1130)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
,"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true}
1465408689376   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1465408689376   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1465408689376   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1465408689378   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1465408689380   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1465408689380   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1465408689380   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1465408689381   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0
1465408689381   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1465408689382   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.2.6
1465408689397   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1465408689398   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1465408689402   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1465408689403   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1465408689650   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1465408689650   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1465408689650   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1465408689652   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1465408689823   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1465408689824   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1465408689827   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1465408689849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1465408689849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1465408689849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1465408689852   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1465408689853   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1465408689878   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1465408689887   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1465408698285   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1465408698286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0
1465408698286   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.2.6
1465408698446   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1465408698447   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1465408698447   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1465408698447   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1465408698447   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1465408698448   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1465408698449   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1465408698449   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1465408698449   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1465408698451   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1465408698453   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Hmm. Kinda looks like you have a hung firefox.exe process that is blocking the driver from starting on the same port?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue after update last night. I'm using MS Test. I uninstalled and re-added drivers via nuget, re-installed Firefox 32bit. Added selenium drivers manually. Nothing solved the problem. Even I'm looking for an answer to this issue. This is the exception I'm getting: `Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055.`

Answer (score 0):

**Good news.**

I just get that resolved on its own. Still wondering.. What i did is i uninstalled Firefox and installed 46.0.0 once again and than i removed my selenium jar from my project. Refreshed my project. Showing Error so again added the same Jars and again did refresh and when i ran my script, i was surprised as it it worked and opened up firefox and processed further.